# Efficient way to remove duplicates from multiple array (array of array of string)

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to figure out an efficient way to remove duplicates from an array of array of string but not within a single array, but from all array.

It's hard to explain so let me show an example:

```
[
  ["Word1", "Word2", "Word3", "Word4"],
  ["Word1", "Word5", "Word3", "Word4"],
  ["Word1", "Word2", "Word3", "Word7"],
]
```

Expected Results:

```
[
  ["Word2", "Word4"],
  ["Word5", "Word4"],
  ["Word2", "Word7"],
]
```

Index 0: Removed because all Index 0 are identicals.

Index 1: Kept because not all Index 1 are identicals.
and so on...

The closer I could come up is

```
def clean_duplicates(attributes)
    valid_attributes = attributes.map { [] }

    attributes.first.count.times.each do |i|
        next if attributes.all? { |v_attrs| v_attrs[i] == attributes.last[i] }

        attributes.each_with_index do |_, v|
            valid_attributes[v].push(attributes[v][i])
        end
    end

    valid_attributes
end

clean_attributes([["Word1", "Word2", "Word3", "Word4"], ["Word1", "Word5", "Word3", "Word4"], ["Word1", "Word2", "Word3", "Word7"]])

=> [["Word2", "Word4"], ["Word5", "Word4"], ["Word2", "Word7"]]
```

Is there a better way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using Array#transpose and Array#select

```
    [["Word1", "Word2", "Word3", "Word4"], ["Word1", "Word5", "Word3", "Word4"], ["Word1", "Word2", "Word3", "Word7"]]
.transpose
.select {|i| i.uniq.size > 1}
.transpose
```

First step is to *transpose* the input to get the following:

```
[["Word1", "Word1", "Word1"], ["Word2", "Word5", "Word2"], ["Word3", "Word3", "Word3"], ["Word4", "Word4", "Word7"]]
```

Then you only want to keep the elements that are not all the same.

```
select { |i| i.uniq.size > 1 }
```

will select only those elements that are not all the same value, giving you:

```
[["Word2", "Word5", "Word2"], ["Word4", "Word4", "Word7"]]
```

finally you *transpose* that into your desired result.

```
transpose
[["Word2", "Word4"], ["Word5", "Word4"], ["Word2", "Word7"]]
```

Comment: I had never seen transpose before ! Smart and elegant ! Thank you!